# Find all the solutions of $(a+1/b)(b+1/a)=4$

Tags: contest-math

I tried to find out some solutions to this equation but I found that it doesn't have any solution, but I couldn't find an elegant solution for this.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: How are you going to find $a$ and $b$ from one equation ?

Answer (score 4):

Multiplying things out gives
$$
ab+\frac1{ab}=2
$$
Which is
$$
\frac{(ab-1)^2}{ab}=0
$$

Answer (score 2):

Well this simply boils down to:

$$(ab+1)^2=4ab$$
$$(ab-1)^2=0$$
$$ab=1$$

carry on forward from here

Answer (score 1):

We have: $(a+1/b)(b+1/a) \ge 4$  by AM-GM inequality. Can you take it from here?